# Retain Cycle in closure in CellView of TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, closures

I am facing retain cycle issue in my ViewController. I have added a closure in my tableview cell to listen click on button as:

```
   var onBtnActionClickHandler: (() -> ())?
```

and calling it as :

```
@objc func btnActionClicked() {
    onBtnActionClickHandler?()
}
```

closure is implemented in cellForRow method as :

```
cell.onBtnActionClickHandler = { [weak self] in
    self?.btnActionClicked()
}
```

but I am facing retain cycle in this process. According to my understanding it should not have strong reference to have retain cycle.
Can anyone explain what is wrong in this process. Thanks

Comment: So your ViewController didn't deallocate after dismissing or after pop? Your example looks fine

Comment: ViewController is poped...

Comment: Ok, so deinit gets called or not?

Comment: How do you know that the ViewController has the retain cycle issue?

Comment: @vpoltave deInit doesn't get called.

Comment: @PGDev in memory graph it has instance for that closure in viewController

Comment: The above code is not the reason for retain cycle. You need to add more code.

Comment: What does your cellForIndexPath look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So I have solved this issue. The problem was not with this cell, acctually a manager class was setting a listener twice and releasing it only once. That was causing reatain cycle in my class.
Thanks for all answers on this question.

Answer (score 0):

The var onBtnActionClickHandler is retained by the cell and a strong reference to your controller?.

You should declare the var inside the cell as weak :

```
weak var onBtnActionClickHandler: (() -> ())?
```